# How to get color (r, g, b ,a) of every pixel in Three.js

Tags: colors, three.js, pixel, particles

I'm using Particle to draw irregular shapes in Three.js, the code snippet is like:

```
var hearts = function(context){

context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
var x = 0, y = 0;
context.scale(0.1, -0.1); // Scale so canvas render can redraw within bounds
context.beginPath();
context.bezierCurveTo(x + 2.5, y + 2.5, x + 2.0, y, x, y);
context.bezierCurveTo(x - 3.0, y, x - 3.0, y + 3.5, x - 3.0, y + 3.5);
...
context.closePath();
context.lineWidth = 0.1; //0.05
context.stroke();
}

var material = new THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial({

program: heart,
blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
});

 material.color.setRGB(255, 0, 0);  
 var particle = new THREE.Particle(material);
```

what I want to do is select the irregular shape properly, my question is, if I draw shape this way, how can I get the color of every pixel so I can used in the picking algorithm

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into toDataURL()?

I use that in my three.js logic to grab and save the canvas out of the browser. From looking at this:

http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/how-to-create-transparency-in-images-with-html5canvas

It looks to me like toDataURL() can also be used to peer into the RGB and A of each pixel, if need be change them and write it back to the visible framebuffer.